# How to run a function from main scope and from on click event with the same syntax

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function with brackets, it suppose to be a part of an "api". It's suppose to have some parameters.
In the example I made an on click event and it working fine.
But when I try to run the function as regular function, it of course doesn't running.
**Important: I need the user to write the function like this: "move(11)"
Thank you**

```
var move = function(steps){
  return function(){
    console.log("moving " + steps + " steps...");
  }
};

// this is what I want
btn.addEventListener("click", move(10));

// this function isn't running because of the return function...but I need the syntax to stay like that
move(20);
```

Comment: Do you want `move(10)` to move, or do you want it to return a function that moves? Either way can satisfy both needs, but you need to pick.

Comment: This doesn't really have much to do with "scope".

Comment: I need the user to write move(20)  on both cases

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I just changed the title

Answer (score 1):

Your `move()` function returns a function. You have to call *that* function in order to make something happen on the console.

```
move(20)();
```

will do that. The call to `move(20)` creates the new function and returns it, and then the `()` after the first call will invoke the returned function and you'll see your message on the console.

Comment: Yes I know that. But I need the user to write move(20) on both cases. Thank you

Comment: Is there a way to know where the function running from ?

Comment: *"I need the user to write move(20) on both cases"* — What does that mean? A function returns what it returns; in your case, it returns a function. You're welcome to write a new function that does different things, but I cannot guess what you're talking about.

Comment: I will explain: I need to write a function that is called "move(steps)". I need to use it only that way, in on click event and when it's running from the main scope. The syntax of the code needs to be :
btn.addEventListener("click", move(10));
move(20);

Comment: @Yalon well unless there's something your function can infer from the "steps" value, that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just rewrite your move function to say

```
var move = function(steps){
    console.log("moving " + steps + " steps...");
};
```

and then you can call it with move(14)

Comment: I need it also in the on click event

Answer (score 0):

So considering the response to Aleksandar's reply from the OP, i'm going to propose that you do what he suggested when it comes to not returning a function and just calling the console log directly from the move function. Then in the add event listener just wrap the move callback with an arrow function like so.

```
const move = steps => console.log(`Moving ${steps} steps...`);
btn.addEventListener('click', () => move(10));
```

This allows you to still use move and call it without running into the issue you are having while still being able to use it as a callback.

Comment: Thank you, but I need the syntax to be as I wrote in the code

Comment: @Yalon if you don't explain **why** you have the requirements you do, nobody can help.

Comment: You should be able to call `move(10)` like you asked with the above and it will work. do you mean the add event listener has to look like `btn.addEventListener('click', move(10))` as well? If so i'm not sure that's possible in JS.

Comment: Yes exactly This is what I need

Comment: I don't think this is possible without either doing like @Pointy said or something like i did above.